# What's the equivalent of "kubectl apply -k" in terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-efs, kustomize

I want to use EFS in my EKS cluster. I'm following this [eks workshop](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/190_efs/).

I need to deploy `EFS CSI Driver` using kustomize:

```
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=release-1.0"
```

What's the equivalent of the above command in terraform?

Is it something like this?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kustomization = {
      source  = "kbst/kustomize"
      version = "0.2.0-beta.3"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}

provider "kustomization" {}

data "kustomization" "test" {
  provider = kustomization

  path = "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/overlays/stable/?ref=release-1.0"
}

resource "kustomization_resource" "test" {
  provider = kustomization

  for_each = data.kustomization.test.ids

  manifest = data.kustomization.test.manifests[each.value]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way you had shown is the correct one for achieving it. You can get more information about the kustomization provider [here](https://github.com/kbst/terraform-provider-kustomization).

Comment: Thanks! I tested it and it was successful but "terraform apply" takes a lot more time than "kubectl -k". Any idea?

Comment: `terraform apply` manages the state in the .tfstate file. On the other hand, the `kubectl -k .` command runs directly. That's maybe one of the reasons.